# React getting error identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux

While am doing some code , am facing some error.
I have the json as

```
{
            "EmployeeId": "3094",
            "sectionName": "A&M Finance",
    },
```

but in React rendering am getting  " &amp" text **between A and M**  then i tried to find a solution for the same and just heard about dangerouslySetInnerHTML , i tried replicating same , but am getting an error like identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected

Here is the piece of code i tried (in rendering am just calling a method truncateMethod,since i need to restrict word length as well )

```
export function truncateMethod(sectionName, length) {
  if (sectionName.length > length) {
    const newVal = dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sectionName }}
    return newVal.slice(0, length).concat('...');
  }
  return newVal;
}
```

Finally what i am trying to achieve is i need to render like **A&M Finance**

Can you guys help me what am trying to do or if you need more explanation am happy to help in comments

So possibly 2 things
-> Either help me to get rid &amp text in react rendering
-> or help me to resolve the error while i use dangerouslysethtml (am getting error identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is used *in the JSX element*](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html), not in defining a `const`.  For example:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={truncateMethod(someString, 10)} />
```

Your method itself also has another bug.  When the `if` condition is `false` then the method returns `undefined` because you never defined `newVal`.  I suspect you meant something like this:

```
export function truncateMethod(sectionName, length) {
    if (sectionName.length > length) {
        return sectionName.slice(0, length).concat('...');
    }
    return sectionName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be because truncateMethod is returning an array

```
 export function truncateMethod(sectionName, length) {
      if (sectionName.length > length) {
        const newVal = dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sectionName }}
        return newVal.slice(0, length).concat('...'); // here it's returning an array
      }
      return sectionName;
    }
```

Fix this to

```
export function truncateMethod(sectionName, length) {
      if (sectionName.length > length) {
        return sectionName.substring(0, length).concat('...'); // return string
      }
      return newVal;
    }
```

And in the JSX you add a parameter like this

```
<Component dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: truncateMethod(sectionName,5) }} />
```